# What exactly is the first argument of select() function

Tags: c, linux, sockets, unix

I don't quite understand the purpose of the first argument in the `select` function. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Select_%28Unix%29) describes it as the maximum file descriptor across all the sets, plus 1 . Why +1 and why does `select` need this information ?

Comment: Maybe it needs to offset it because it considers valid file descriptor numbers from `1 to n`, not `0 to (n - 1)`.

Answer (score 5):

In *Nix systems, file descriptors are just indexes into a system table, and the `fd_set` structure contains a bitmask that corresponds to those indexes.  When a descriptor is added to an `fd_set`, the corresponding bit is enabled.  `select()` needs to know the highest descriptor value so it can loop through the bits and know which one to stop at.

On Windows, sockets are represented by handles to kernel objects, not by indexes.  The `fd_set` structure contains an array of socket handles and a counter of the number of sockets in the array.  This way, `select()` can just loop through the array, and is thus why the first parameter of `select()` is ignored on Windows.

Comment: So why the author doesn't make `fd_set` as a linked list?

Answer (score 3):

This is a happenstance detail of the (original) Berkeley sockets implementation. Basically, the implementation used the *number* of file descriptors as a sizing variable for some temporary internal bit arrays.  Since Unix descriptors start with zero, the largest descriptor would be one less than the *size* of any array with a one-slot-per-descriptor semantic.  Hence the "largest-plus-one" requirement.  This plus-1 adjustment could have been absorbed into the system call itself, but wasn't.

Ancient history, that's all. The result is that the correct interpretation of the first argument has less to do with descriptor *values* than with the *number* of them (i.e. the maximum number of descriptors to be tested).   See Section 6.3 of [Stevens et al](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131411551) (This is a revised and updated version of Rich Stevens' classic text.  If you don't have it, get it!)

Comment: That makes sense about the plus 1. Thank you for the answer and for the link. If I have understood Remy Lebeau answer and yours do the internal bit arrays contain bit elements that get enabled when a descriptor is added ?

Comment: In the original Berkeley implementation, the internal bit arrays are assembled afresh for each system call.  No state is maintained across calls. Rich Stevens covered the gory details too, [here](http://www.amazon.com/TCP-IP-Illustrated-Implementation-Vol/dp/020163354X)

Answer (score 1):

The ideia is that the first parameter can be used by the select function to optimize the timing reading the fd_set.

In the manual:

```
man select
```

it says:

> nfds is the highest-numbered file descriptor in any of the three sets, plus 1.

So the select function only checks for the fds smaller than this on in the fd_set and not all of the possible fds in the fd_set. This size is defined in the FD_SETSIZE constant.

Comment: That makes no sense. An `fd_set` can have multiple values in it. If `select()` "only checks for the fds smaller than this on in the fd_set and not all of the possible fds in the fd_set", it would be skipping values.

Comment: @RemyLebeau nfds is supposed to be the file descriptor with the highest value + 1. i.e. if you place file descriptors 5, 9 , 90 in the fd_set , you set the nfd argument to 91. Any file descriptors you've placed in the fd_set is less than 91 - and none of the descriptors you're interested in will be skipped.

Comment: I understand what `nfd` is. Look at the wording of your answer, though: "the select function only checks for the fds smaller than this on in the fd_set **and not all of the possible fds in the fd_set**".  That implies that values added to the fd_set could be skipped. Just fix your wording to make it clearer that `select()` does not check all possible fds, just the fds actually added to the fd_set.

Comment: Well, descriptors will indeed be skipped if you add descriptors with values >= the nfds argument,

Answer (score 1):

In most UNIX kernel ABIs, the `fd_set *` arguments to `select` are actually `unsigned *` or `unsigned long *` that point to arrays of words containing bits.  The first argument to `select` tells the kernel how large those arrays are and how many bits should be checked.

Each word contains 16 or 18 or 32 or 36 or 64 bits (depending on the wordsize of the machine); the kernel will read `nfds/wordsize` words from user space, using `nfds%wordsize` low-order bits from the last words (and all the bits of the other words).

The `fd_set` data structure and related functions were introduced by POSIX to have an easy way  of managing these bitsets that could also be portable to other systems that used some other representation and the kernel ABI level.